# Loading image in picturebox from database

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox, windows

i've tried the following code for loading an image in picturebox from database. but everytime , i get an error like '**`paramater is  not valid`**'.

```
buttonSave()
            {
                .......
                .......
                img = Image.FromFile(strFileName);
                byte[] byteImg = ImageToByteArray(img);
                objEmp.Picture = byteImg;
                .......
                .......
            } 

public byte[] ImageToByteArray(Image img)
        {
            System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }  

Display()
       { 
           .......
           .......
           Byte[] bytePicData = (Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["PICTURE"];                
           MemoryStream stmPicData = new MemoryStream(bytePicData);
           PicBox.Image = Bitmap.FromStream(stmPicData);} 
           .......
           .......
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

the image is corrupt.  The error is from the FromStream method.  Can you write to disk and see if you can open it in an image view.  If not then check the code where you are inserting it into the database

```
Byte[] bytePicData = (Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["PICTURE"];
// Save
File.WriteAllBytes("out.bmp", bytePicData);

MemoryStream stmPicData = new MemoryStream(bytePicData);
PicBox.Image = BitMap.FromStream(stmPicData);
```

Comment: File.WriteAllBytes("out.bmp", bytePicData); statement also added

Comment: Can you open out.bmp in mspaint or another image viewer?  It might be the image is being saved to the db incorrectly.  Your code here looks okay